# Can the F test be generalized for a null hyp where variances are unequal?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, variance

Sorry for the question, maybe this appears in a book a little more advanced than the ones I have seen.

Suppose we have two samples from normal distributions with sample variances $S_{n,1}^2$ and $S_{m,2}^2$, and population variances $\sigma_{n,1}^2$ and $\sigma_{m,2}^2$

F test for equality of variances says that if $\sigma_1=\sigma_2$, then

$F:=\frac{S_{n,1}^2}{S_{m,2}^2}\sim F(n-1,m-1)$,

As far as I understand, this comes from the facts that:

1. $\frac{S_n^2}{\sigma^2}\sim\chi^2_{n-1}$, and
2. $X\sim\chi^2_\nu, Y\sim\chi^2_{\xi}\rightarrow\frac{\xi}{\nu}\cdot\frac{X}{Y}\sim F(\nu,\xi)$

But in that case, one could set $H_0: \frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1}=k$, and then the statistic:

$F:=\frac{\frac{S_{n,1}^2}{\sigma_1^2}}{\frac{S_{m,2}^2}{\sigma_2^2}}=\frac{\sigma_2^2}{\sigma_1^2}\frac{S_{n,1}^2}{S_{m,2}^2}=k^2\frac{S_{n,1}^2}{S_{m,2}^2}$,
should also be distributed according to $F(n-1,m-1)$.

Am I right?, did I make some wrong assumption I didn't notice?

If I'm right, what is this test called?

Comment: I don't know that it has a specific name beyond being a test of variances, but consider that you're just testing the equality of variance of one variable and a new variable that is $k$ times your other variable, so it's still just an equality of variance test / variance ratio test with an extra step (defining a new variable). I'd name it in much the same way I'd name a two sample t-test that hypothesized $\mu_2 = \mu_1+\delta$; that's still a t-test and still a test of means)

Comment: Thanks, @Glen_b